# How would I set the CSS property as a condition in if statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, grid

I've got an issue to set the CSS property as a condition of if statement.

My goal is to reset the values of specific div when the condition is true. For example, when the `.inline-grid`'s left property goes to -200% or 200%, reset the left property to 0 every time so it looks like repeat the contents forever.

So I tried to compare the CSS property between the value but it didn't work.

It's really hard to figure out because the browser doesn't show any kinds of error messages on the console panel.

This is my code.

*SOF preview has an error to run my code. You may check this in [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Maldit/pen/mvJPzM).

```js
$(function swipeInit() {
  /* Variables */
  var _ = $('#swipe > .container > .grid > .inline-grid'),
      myList = _.find('ul'),
      myItem = myList.find('li'),
      beforeClone = myItem.first().before(myItem.last().clone()),
      afterClone = myItem.last().after(myItem.first().clone());

  /* Actions */
  var swipeAction = () => {
        myList.animate({
          left: '-=' + 100 + '%'
        }, () => {
          /* -- This part doesn't work -- */
          if (myList.css('left') == (-200 + '%')) {
            myList.css({
              left: 500 + '%'
            });
          }
          /* -- This part doesn't work -- */
        });
      }
      swipeLoop = setInterval(() => {
        swipeAction();
      }, 2000);
 
  /* Logs */
  console.log(myList);
})
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul li {
    list-style: none;
}
#swipe {

}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
    justify-content: center;
}
.grid {
    position: relative;
    width: 1170px;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px dashed black;
}
.inline-grid {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.cell {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
    justify-content: center;
}
._contents {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- Swipe -->
<section id="swipe">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="inline-grid">
        <ul class="cell">
          <li class="_contents">
            <p>Test Swipe Title 1</p>
            <p>consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          </li>
          <li class="_contents">
            <p>Test Swipe Title 2</p>
            <p>consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          </li>
          <li class="_contents">
            <p>Test Swipe Title 3</p>
            <p>consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- /end Swipe -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you wouldnt rewrite a `.css` file, use inline html style using jquery.

Comment: @weber Sorry. I don't understand what you are saying. Could you explain a bit detail?

Comment: `css('left')` return values in `px` not `%` so no, you can't do that this way.

Comment: @Oen44 Aw that's a bad news ._. thx for commenting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to get `width` of `ul` and get -200% of that value in pixels. Then you compare `left` to what you got.

#### Changes

```
var ulWidth = myList.width()
if (parseInt(myList.css('left')) == parseInt(ulWidth * -2)) {
    myList.css({
        left: 100 + '%'
    });
}
$(window).resize(function() {
    ulWidth = myList.width();
});
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/oen44/pen/MLwjQE)

Comment: This is brilliant idea but when I change the resolution using `CTRL` + mousewheel it goes collapsing.

Comment: I just did that, zoomed in, out, changed window resolution, it's scaling very well.

Comment: Hmm that's weird. For me, when I zoom in or out during swipe, the left property changes to -300%.

Comment: Appreciate your help. Thank you so much :>